# Rpart and subsets

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I am getting unexpected results from an rpart model, where the model selects two variables, one of which is a subset of the other. This in itself is not unexpected, but the seemingly odd thing is that the decision tree uses a higher threshold for the subset variable than the less granular variable, which makes no logical sense to me.

To give an edited version of my problem (as the real problem is business-sensitive): let's say I want to train a model to predict whether somebody will default on a loan, with the inputs being the number of different types of toy owned by each person.

After training the model, I visualise the rpart and see that My Little Pony™ is the killer. The model predicts that, as long as you own fewer than 20 My Little Pony™ dolls, you will not default on your loan. However, owning 20 or more My Little Pony™ dolls does not necessarily mean that you will default. The tree has a 2nd layer for those with 20 or more My Little Pony™ dolls, which determines that anybody with 60 or more *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls will default on their loan.

In the below diagram, "MLP" stands for total My Little Pony™ dolls owned; "MLP-Pink" is the number of *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls owned. For the outputs, 1 denotes a default; 0 means no default.

[image: rpart model to determine risk of loan default based on My Little Pony™ ownership]

To me, this makes no sense. 1) Pink My Little Pony™ dolls are a subset of total My Little Pony™ dolls; 2) the threshold for *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls is higher than the threshold for total My Little Pony™ dolls, so the first node of the tree (split based on total My Little Pony™ dolls) is inconsequential. If you have 60 *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls, then by definition you must have more than 20 My Little Pony™ dolls in total. Nevertheless, this is what the model spits out. And yes, I have checked whether there are any weird bugs in the data where people somehow have more *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls than total My Little Pony™ dolls - there aren't any. Unsurprisingly, when I code my decision engine with or without the >=20 My Little Pony™ dolls threshold, it makes no difference.

This doesn't seem like a problem as such, as I can simply write my code to look at *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls and do away with the total, but it still bothers me. Does anybody have a good enough understanding of what goes on under the hood to have some idea as to why rpart might do this? Am I barking up the wrong tree by attempting to train a decision tree using both subsets and totals as inputs?

I am also curious - tangentially - as to why ownership of *pink* My Little Pony™ dolls would be a determining factor in one's ability to service one's debts, but I suspect such a discussion would be deemed off-topic.